# Access UITextField from custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, class, uitextfield

I'm trying to create a custom auto-complete `UITextField`. I'm trying to figure out how to start.

My setup will be something like this: I'm gonna have to subclass the `class` to `UITableView` -  `@interface MyClass : UITableView`. I have a property in `MyClass` of a `UITextField` called `toTextField`.

How can I make `toTextField` equal `toTextField`?

(I know it's possible because this project has the same type of thing. [AutoComplete](https://github.com/raulzito234/AutoCompleteTableViewController/blob/master/AutoFillTableViewController.m#L37). That's not my project.)

I'm gonna be setting the `textField's` (from the storyboard) class to my custom class. (`MyClass`)

---

If this isn't clear, please ask in the comments for clarification.

Comment: Nothing about this question is clear. What is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry. So frustrated, I can't think straight!! I'm trying to create a custom auto-complete UITextField class. just like this one: https://github.com/raulzito234/AutoCompleteTableViewController How can I  access the textField (from the storyboard) I assigned this current class to?

Comment: Are you asking about how to use the `UITextField` from your storyboard in code? This is still very unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to create something like this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: i get it your question ,well you should https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField use this controls or if you want to made by yourself than raywendrlich's is the best tuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an IBOutlet and link it with the text field within your storyboard.

```
@interface MyClass : UITableView{
     IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
}
```

Then you can reference the text field with whatever name you gave it in your code.

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
myClass.toTextField = myTextField.text;
```

Comment: Should I subclass it as a UITableView, or UITableVIewController?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Have you set your view in the storyboard to be using your custom class? Go to Storyboard > click on view controller > go to Identity Inspector > make sure "custom class" is the same as your view controller .h/.m file
You should subclass it to whatever type of view controller you're using. I just used UITableView as an example in my response above.

Answer (score 0):

- Actually 1st problem with your approach is you want to make a library
  using `storyboard`.
- 2nd problem is you want to subclass `tableview` for
  this.

> May be you will be able to implement this in your way but that would
>   be difficult to manage for you.

- I think, you don't need to use any interface builder to do this thing.
- You must subclass `UIView` and add a `textfield` and `tableview` in it.
  When user will start typing and it will match some results then show the `tableview` and increase your view's height otherwise close the `tableview` and reduce the height of view to the `textfield` height.